# Power Query add Month Column in dependent on Index

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm new in "Excel PowerQuery" and now if got a little problem with it. I've got a table with only an index (0,1,2,3...) and some values. Now I need a "NewDateColumn" with monthly interval for all index values.

Example:

```
Index  Values  NewDateColumn 
0      a       10/2019
1      b       11/2019
2      c       12/2019
3      d       01/2020
...    ...
n      z       07/2020
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create you new custom column like below(with your preferred date)

[image]

Create a duplicate column and transform it like below and then you can remove the original Date column

[image]

Comment: Tank you. I changed "AddDays" to "AddMonths" and now it look great.